# Multiple order by data in mysql doesn't show right

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have been order by data with multiple field, i don't know is it possible or not. here is my [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/723a6/4) please guide me how to code get the results

```
SELECT product_date, TIME_FORMAT(`product_time`,'%H:%i') as time  ,product_akurat, product_tidak_akurat
FROM `li_product_post` 
order by product_date desc, time desc, product_akurat desc, product_tidak_akurat asc
```

i have been trying many times how can i get data by order by

1. New data inserted by date and time
2. Data with big number in field product_akurat
3. Data with big number in field product_tidak_akurat

all i want is data came with this

```
november, 01 2015  | 10:41  |   1          0  
november, 01 2015  | 11:27  |   1          1  
november, 10 2015  | 10:39  |   0          1

november, 14 2015  | 17:16  |   0          6
```

want to order by date and time desc but in other hand i want to put values with highest product_akurat in the first rows then put in the bottom which is product has highest product_tidak_akurat

Comment: A later ordering is only used when the rows have the same value of all the previous ordering columns. All your times are different.

Comment: so you mean it is not possible to multiple order by even some rows has same value?
in my demo give me only order product_tidak_akurat asc doesn't working

Comment: What rows do you want first in your result set? Those with the latest date, or those with the highest values in those `product_*` columns?

Comment: In your demo they're ordered only by date and time. Coincidentally, all the newer rows also have `product_akurat = 0`.

Comment: Please show what your desired result is.

Comment: ya @Barmar i create data with diffrent date, then trying to testing order by product_akurat has highest value then product_tidak_akurat low values

product_akurat (up)
product_tidak_akurat (down)

it seems like voting but depends on time create, which is data has product_akurat high, (date and time desc) will be first rows even data has product_tidak_akurat highest will be bottom ?

Comment: wiil update the question

Comment: Please add more rows to your example. Multiple `ORDER BY` columns are used to break ties, but you don't have any ties in `product_akurat` and `product_tidak_akurat`.

Comment: sorry bamar what is ties ? i'm new in this forum
ties seems like mark or signs, should i insert it or what, thanks

Comment: A tie is when two things have the same value. Like when a football game ends with both teams having the same score, it's a tie.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
ORDER BY product_akurat DESC, product_tidat_akurat, product_date DESC, time DESC
```

This will just use the date and time to order within the rows that have the same `product_akurat` and `product_tidat_akurat`.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/723a6/9)

Comment: wew cool bamar, i don't know why i'm become stupid !
because the first priority  by get time and date make me think a lot, why i cannot vote up your question to help someone in the future, 
+1

but bamar how can i make data with new without has value product_akurat and tidak_akurat, i should put this data in the first rows ?

Comment: Your query giving close with the results, but in other hand i want put new data (get by date and time) in the top even data has product_akurat='0' and product_tidak_akurat='0'